# Background image not visible

Tags: html, css, image

http://jpshots.com/portrait.html

If you look in the CSS, you will see that there should be an image surrounding the mini nav. I'm fairly confident that the file are all proper because all of the other img's work properly.

I originally put the image in the HTML, but it was tricky because I concluded that the image was sitting on top of the nav, making the links un-clickable. Normally i would use a z-index but z-index's need to be relative, which then presents a problem with positioning it in the bottom right corner. Any help would be fabulous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console shows `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
The image file you're referring to is not found, probably due to an error in the url in your css.

Look at the `background-image` attribute in your `.bottom-nav` declaration found in *basic.css* file :

```
background-image: url(".../img/mininav.png");
```

I'm pretty sure there's one dot too much here. This should work :

```
background-image: url("../img/mininav.png");
```